# Is that possible to generate and download a csv or xls on the fly without using "contentType="text/csv#Export.csv"

Tags: csv

I already tried to generate a csv of my list by create a separate vf page with the page attribute

```
contentType="text/csv#Export.csv"
```

Is that possible to generate and download a csv on the fly without using "contentType="text/csv#Export.csv"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need the contentType, but they can be rolled into one page. You can use a merge field to control which output to use. For example:

```
<apex:page controller="listpage" contentType="{!contentType}">
    <!-- your content here, rendered based on content type... -->
    <apex:form rendered="{!contentType='text/html'}">
        <apex:commandButton value="Export" action="{!export}" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And the controller:

```
public class listpage {
    public string contentType { get; set; }
    public listpage() {
        contentType = 'text/html';
    }
    public void export() {
        contentType = 'text/csv#export.csv';
    }
}
```

**NOTE** You'll need to do more than just this to make sure the headers are not emitted, etc based on the content type. It may be easier to just use a separate page, but it's certainly *possible* to make it a single page.